# How to fix the data flow task errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a problem with the SQL Server agent job, that keeps on failing. So there is a package created on the SSIS and I have process like create excel sheet and also the data flow task.

The problem begins when it start to fail on the Data Flow task, and the problem is about excel destination and primeoutput failed. The problem statements are:

> 1. Data Flow Task: Error SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.The PrimeOutput method on OLE DB Source returned error code 0xC02020C4. The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
> 2. Data Flow Task: Error SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "Excel Destination"(124) failed with error code 0xC0202009 while processing input "Excel Destination input"(135). The Identified component, but the error is fatal and will cause Data Flow Task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

What I tried is I went to the SSIS packages on my visual studio and try to change that field called DelayValidation to true, and also maximum error count to 1,10, or 1000, I tried them. So am not sure now, what to check and how can I do that.

Am expecting it to run without any of those excel errors and the data flow task errors.

Comment: okay thank you for editing it

Comment: @Madonado no worries i upvoted it since i doesn't deserve to be downvoted

Comment: @Hadi appriciated

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: try switching your project to 32bit in debug options

Comment: @Scotch yes i did that exaclty before seeing your comment and it wasn't working because of excel connection manager, but i created new excel connection manager and it worked.32bit is the way. thank you guys for your help.

Comment: since this problem was resolved via comments, is there someone who will close this since i only got comment which was right from @Scotch, Thank you.

Comment: @Scotch if i may ask, my job was running yesterday but today it's complaining about the same issue and am using 32bit, is there anything i can do beside deploying my ssis package

Comment: @Madonado are you running it locally from visual studio or do you have it deployed to SSISDB?

Comment: @Scotch locally, but it's no longer failing, thank you.